# css3 adaptive image in absolute position

Tags: html, image, css, responsive-design, image-scaling

I'm stuck on something that should be very simple. I have a page that uses Semantic UI. On that page I have a logo image that is 200px wide by 388px high. The image is positioned absolutely, top left. It does not use any Semantic UI class. I want the image to shrink adaptively to the screen size. I have played about with min and max heights and widths, but the image will not change size at all.

The only way I got it to almost work was to replace the image with a div and set the image as a background. I got that adapting, but I couldn't maintain aspect ratio, and besides, that's not a satisfactory solution.

Here's an example of what I have;

```
<div class="ui inverted menu">....</div>
<img src="/img.png" class="logo">
<div class="ui page grid">.....</div>

/* css (separate file) */
.logo{
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px; 
    left: 6px; 
    z-index: 2;
    min-height: 100px;
    max-height: 388px;
    width: auto;
}
```

This is just one of many variants I have tried and I have run out of ideas!

Answer (score 0):

The best solution will be to put the image as a `background-image` and than set the `background-size` to `cover`.

```
.logo {
  background-image: url(path/to/your/image.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

This way, you'll maintain aspect ratio.
If you don't want parts of your image to be cut off, you can use `background-size: contain;` instead.

Comment: Thanks, but as I explained, I already tried using it as a background image, but 1) it wasn't successful and 2) It isn't the desired method. Also one of the issues is that the container covers clickable items, so one has to start adding border radius to shape it to the image. It's a messy work around that shouldn't be necessary! :)

Answer (score 0):

There is an `object-fit/object-position` method for your problem.

To keep aspect ratio for an `img` block just use:

```
object-fit: contain;
```

For placing img top left:

```
object-position: 0 0;
```

Don't forget to stretch image to 100% width and height:

```
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

Check out [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/py7pa2xj/1/) to play with it.

Please notice that this variant is not the best for cross-browser using, since there is no support for `object-fit/object-position` properties in IE 6-11, Edge and some Mobile Android browsers according to [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit).

As **Simon** said before, I'd reccomend you using [background-image](https://caniuse.com/#search=background-size) for cases like this too.